# What does the sup function mean in the context of metrics for probability measures/distances/differences?

Tags: probability-theory, metric-spaces

I was studying different probability metrics and distances and came across the following source:

http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781461448686-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1368104-p174541769

At one point they define the Uniform/kolmogorov metric as:

$$\rho(X,Y) := sup\{ |F_X(x) - F_y(x) | : x \in R\}$$

I am guessing that they mean by F the probability distribution of F, but what I am a little confused is what the $sup$ function is suppose to be. What does sup mean?

I am specifically trying to understand what the uniform metric means, but I don't really know what the sup function is suppose to return.

Could you also provide a couple of examples of what $sup$ is suppose to return/give?

Comment: $\sup A$ is the supremum of the set $A$, the least upper bound.

Comment: Do you mean $sup(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = max(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$?

Comment: For a finite set, the supremum is the maximum indeed, but for an infinite (bounded) set, the maximum need not exist, while the supremum does. e.g. $$\sup \left\{ 1 - \tfrac{1}{n} : n \geqslant 1\right\} = 1,$$ but the set contains no maximum.

Answer (score 1):

$\sup$ means supremum, which is the least upper bound of a set. So for your example,

$$\sup\{ |F_X(x) - F_y(x) | : x \in R\}$$

would return the least upper bound of $|F_X(x) - F_y(x) |$ for all $x\in{R}$.

Comment: The largest difference? so $sup(1,2,3) = 3$?

Comment: There may not be a largest value. That's why we use least upper bound since it generalizes the idea of maximum. If $\max S$ exists, then $\max S=\sup S$.

Comment: @Pinocchio, that is correct except there may be no "largest distance" obtained within the set, in that case the $\sup$ lies just outside the set.

Comment: Yes, MPW is correct. So the supremum of $\{x:x^2<2\}$ would be $\sqrt{2}$ even though that is not in the set.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what sup would return when there is no largest distance? (sorry I am not very familiar with this, it seems its basic knowledge on this field).

Comment: @Pinocchio you can construct an example (see my answer below vv)

Comment: @Pinocchio You can usually think of it like a limit, as you approach the value that maximizes the distance (which, to clarify again, need not exist in the set). All of the examples on this page show that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (0, 5 - 1/n)$.  Then $\sup (A) = 5$ by using the definitions, but $5 \notin A$.